# Checkbox processing - how to construct e-mail showing choices?

Tags: forms

My name is Rafael and I'm a noob. I'm writing a form for my webpage, where a client can choose different articles. I'm doing it via checkboxes:

The part of the form looks like this:

```
 <form action="save-order.php" method="post" class="sky-form">
    <header><center>Formularz zamówienia</center></header>

    <fieldset>
      <section>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-12">
          <h3>Prosimy o wybór artykułów z poniższej listy.</h3>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł1" value="Otto Kernberg 19 zł"><i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł2" value="Marta Badoni 19 zł"><i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł3" value="John Steiner 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł4" value="Zachrisoson 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł5" value="Etchegoyen 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł6" value="adfadfg 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł7" value="adf 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł8" value="adfads dasfda 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł9" value="adf daf 19 zł"> <i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
            <label class="checkbox state-success"><input type="checkbox" name="artykuł10" value="adf dfasfd 19 zł"><i></i>Ograniczenia zdolności do kochania - Otto Kernberg 19 zł</label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
    </fieldset>
```

Then, I try to get the choices in my second file, which is intended to process the form. I wanted to assign the data from a form only and only when the selection was made. I try to do it here:

```
if(isset($_POST["artykuł1"])) {
$artykul1 = $_POST["artykuł1"]; }

if(isset($_POST["artykuł2"]))
$artykul2 = $_POST["artykuł2"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł3"]))
$artykul3 = $_POST["artykuł3"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł4"]))
$artykul4 = $_POST["artykuł4"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł5"]))
$artykul5 = $_POST["artykuł5"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł6"]))
$artykul6 = $_POST["artykuł6"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł7"]))
$artykul7 = $_POST["artykuł7"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł8"]))
$artykul8 = $_POST["artykuł8"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł9"]))
$artykul9 = $_POST["artykuł9"];

if(isset($_POST["artykuł10"]))
$artykul10 = $_POST["artykuł10"];
```

However, I must be doing something very, very wrong. When I construct the body message, I get nonsense. The variables are both set and not set:) I just want to show only the titles - choices, that were chosen in the form...

Can you help me please? I spent three days trying to figure it out. Where am I mistaken?

```
 // Construct subject of the email
  $subject = 'Zeszyt I Przeglad Psychoanalityczny - przedsprzedaż';

  // Construct email body
  $body_message = $message = "<html> 
  <body>

<?php if(isset($artykul1)) { ?>
        Isset
<?php } ?>

<?php if(!isset($artykul1)) { ?>
        Not Isset
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try and remove that weird unicode special character ł in all of your variable names. Like this, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="artyku1"
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST["artyku1"])) {
$artykul1 = $_POST["artyku1"];
}
```

Comment: Did so - nothing changes. Still the same effect, showing both - isset and not isset in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code how to generate and send the mail are wrong. By looking at the above code you provided, you are starting a string and then using "?php" tags inside that string. I think that's not how string concatenation works.
Please try this:

```
$body_message = "<html><body>".
                "  artykul1 = ".$artykul1.
                ", artykul2 = ".$artykul2.
                ", artykul3 = ".$artykul3.
                " ...</body></html>";

$message = $body_message; // don't know why you would need two identical variables
```

If this doesn't help you, please provide all of your code to generate and send the email.